# RDP Black screen

Tags: server, 20.04, remote-desktop, xrdp, rdp

I installed XRDP on Ubuntu 20.04 Webserver and also added the GNOME Desktop.

It had been very slow and laggy. I found details online advising to navigate to `etc/xrdp` and edit `xrdp.ini` It advised that I change `crypt_level=High` to `crypt_level=None`

I done this and when I tried logging in using Remote Desktop Connection and the Ubuntu Desktop was locked, I entered my password but it would not accept it
I then restarted XRDP to see if that solved the problem, but now I have a black screen, I looged out and back in and the screen is still black

The server is running Ubuntu 20.04
I am accessing the service GUI form a WIndows 10 computer using Remote Desktop connection

Any help would be much appreciated

/var/log/xrdp.log

```
[20220630-18:55:59] [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:82.25.245.114 port 54503
[20220630-18:55:59] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:87.106.254.254 port 3389)
[20220630-18:55:59] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
[20220630-18:55:59] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20220630-18:55:59] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20220630-18:55:59] [DEBUG] TLSv1.3 enabled
[20220630-18:55:59] [DEBUG] TLSv1.2 enabled
[20220630-18:55:59] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 11, selected 1
[20220630-18:55:59] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:87.106.254.254 port 3389)
[20220630-18:55:59] [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:82.25.245.114 port 54504
[20220630-18:55:59] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:87.106.254.254 port 3389)
[20220630-18:55:59] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
[20220630-18:55:59] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20220630-18:55:59] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20220630-18:55:59] [DEBUG] TLSv1.3 enabled
[20220630-18:55:59] [DEBUG] TLSv1.2 enabled
[20220630-18:55:59] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 11, selected 1
[20220630-18:56:00] [INFO ] connected client computer name: XXXX
[20220630-18:56:00] [INFO ] adding channel item name rdpdr chan_id 1004 flags 0x80800000
[20220630-18:56:00] [INFO ] adding channel item name rdpsnd chan_id 1005 flags 0xc0000000
[20220630-18:56:00] [INFO ] adding channel item name cliprdr chan_id 1006 flags 0xc0a00000
[20220630-18:56:00] [INFO ] adding channel item name drdynvc chan_id 1007 flags 0xc0800000
[20220630-18:56:00] [INFO ] TLS connection established from ::ffff:82.25.245.114 port 54504: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
[20220630-18:56:00] [DEBUG] xrdp_0000acff_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
[20220630-18:56:00] [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000809.ini
[20220630-18:56:01] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00000809 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
[20220630-18:56:01] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
[20220630-18:56:01] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
[20220630-18:56:01] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sending login info to session manager, please wait...
[20220630-18:56:01] [DEBUG] return value from xrdp_mm_connect 0
[20220630-18:56:03] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login failed for display 0
[20220630-18:56:03] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20220630-18:56:04] [DEBUG] Closed socket 18 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 42180)
[20220630-18:56:10] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
[20220630-18:56:10] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
[20220630-18:56:10] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sending login info to session manager, please wait...
[20220630-18:56:10] [DEBUG] return value from xrdp_mm_connect 0
[20220630-18:56:10] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for display 11
[20220630-18:56:10] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: started connecting
[20220630-18:56:10] [INFO ] lib_mod_log_peer: xrdp_pid=44287 connected to X11rdp_pid=42490 X11rdp_uid=0 X11rdp_gid=0 client_ip=::ffff:82.25.245.114 client_port=54504
[20220630-18:56:10] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connected ok
[20220630-18:56:10] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: chansrv connect successful
[20220630-18:56:10] [DEBUG] Closed socket 18 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 42192)
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who is interested, I managed to solve the problem by navigating to /etc/xrdp/ and editing file startwm.sh

I added

```
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
```

here

```
if test -r /etc/profile; then
    . /etc/profile
fi
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR

if test -r /etc/default/locale; then
    . /etc/default/locale
    test -z "${LANG+x}" || export LANG
```

Comment: This means the session will not be started with working dbus or runtime directory. This causes a broken session. It's better to add dbus-launch --exit-with-session startplasma-x11 to xsession.

Answer (score 3):

I installed xrdp and spent about half a day reading through forums trying to get it working. My issue was that I was using the account that I installed Ubuntu with (darren). Created a new account and added to xrdp group. Worked straight away and has been working without issue since. I dont know why it worked but I can connect now.

Comment: The user you create during install is not root by default. If it was you would never have to use sudo when logged in as that user. There is no root user by default in Ubuntu. Your answer may be correct create a user but not for the reason you give.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @David you are right. It's not the root account. Edited answer